# Minimize $L^\infty$ norm of complex vector

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers

What is the best way to solve this optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\min_\mathbf{x} \||\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}|\|_\infty,
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{b}$ are complex, and $|\cdot|$ denotes the modulus/magnitude of the complex vector entries?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's a relatively straightforward exercise to formulate this as a second-order cone programming problem after breaking everything into real and imaginary components.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I was able to formulate it as a linear programming problem by splitting the real and imaginary components: $\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf{A}_r & -\mathbf{A}_i \\ \mathbf{A}_i & \mathbf{A}_r\end{matrix}\right]\left\{\begin{matrix}\mathbf{x}_r \\ \mathbf{x}_i\end{matrix}\right\}-\left\{\begin{matrix}\mathbf{b}_r \\ \mathbf{b}_i\end{matrix}\right\}$ to obtain the smallest component across all elements.  Would the second-order cone programming problem be more computationally expensive?

Comment: You can't find the absolute value of a complex number from its real and imaginary parts without taking the square root of the sum of the squares.  That's why you need SOCP.  Minimizing the largest of the real and imaginary parts isn't actually minimizing the infinity norm.

Comment: @BrianBorchers couldn't we avoid the square root and just take the sum of the squares?

Comment: You could minimize the square of the infinity norm of $Ax-b$, but that would be a convex QP rather than an LP.  In practice, it's often simplest to solve convex QP's as SOCP's.